# With what command is possible know the RAM's DDR type, Speed and Frequency by each slot?

Tags: upgrade, command, hardware, ram

For a computer, such as laptop or server used for developing and server purposes respectively and taking in consideration that can't be opened.

With what command is possible know the following specs of the RAM installed for each slot?

- DDR type
- Speed
- Frequency (MHz) - *mostly this one*

Not always the Ram's box and Ram's sticker contains that info together.

Comment: seriously, you got all the answers before. It's as if you ask for a command, then ignore 99% of its output. This question is not founded on sufficient own reading, hence my downvote.

Comment: In the other Question (with that title - ECC/Non-ECC and Buffered/Unbuffered) how is expected that other members of this community get straight information about (DDR type, Speed and Frequency?) Different content to request - but yes, same command involved, perhaps not obvious for other members. Furthermore the "ignored" data is not visible at a first glance in the 2nd block of the output. I created this question taking in consideration other set of specific data to be available for the community.

Comment: The question is always "how do I query memory properties". And you got the answer the first time: `dmidecode -t memory`. You're not contributing anything by repeating the same question for all fields that this delives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with your previous questions, `dmidecode -t memory`:

```
Handle 0x0050, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x004C
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 72 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8 GB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMMB2
        Bank Locator: P0_Node0_Channel1_Dimm1
        Type: DDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1600 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Samsung
        Part Number: M391B1G73BH0-CK0
        Rank: 2
        Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s
```

Note the “Type” and the two “Speed” entries. The “Locator” entry identifies the slot.

Comment: What field represents the frequency? does not appear the `MHz` unit

Comment: @ManuelJordan hint: wikipedia.

Comment: Also, it really seems you just care about someone spelling out for you which RAM you need to buy to upgrade your long-obsolete notebook. That has already been answered in comments to current and now-deleted posts of yours. And: this is a 15 year old subnotebook with a least-cost processor. No amount of RAM you can put in there even puts it in the same league as a modern smart phone, leave alone a laptop of the last 8 years.

Comment: The upgrade situation applies for other 4 laptops ... So I deleted the mentioned OP to avoid confusions in give the incorrect focus to just old specific notebook.

Comment: `What field represents the frequency?` the Speed

Comment: @ManuelJordan DDR frequency is measured in transfers per second, not cycles. The memory shown in the answer is DDR3-1600 (which uses an 800MHz clock).